# Trying to edit a component through a dialog box that opens with specific info for that record

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-reactive-forms

I have a list of servers that I am making a angular browser for to display them. The user can add/delete/edit this list that is connected to a SQL database. I can open the dialog window to edit the entry, but I would like the current values to appear in the input boxes. How can I do this? It should open the entry in which row the edit button was clicked. Currently I am getting an error saying it cannot read property `serverId` of undefined. This is what I have.

(server-service.services.ts)

```js
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    serverId: new FormControl(null),
    serverName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    appId: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    domain: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    environment: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
})
populateForm(server) {
    this.form.setValue(server);
}
```

(server-list.component.ts)

```js
onEdit(row) {
    this.serverService.populateForm(row);
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "475px";
    this.dialog.open(ServerEditComponent, dialogConfig);
}
```

(server-edit.component.html)

```html
<form [formGroup]="serverForm" class="form">
   <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="startcenter">
      <mat-form-field>
         <input matInput placeholder="Server Name" type="text"       formControlName="serverName" required autofocus>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
         <mat-label>Application</mat-label>
         <mat-select formControlName="appId" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let application of applicationList" [value]="application.appId">
            {{application.appName}}
            </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <br />
   </div>
   <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="startcenter">
      <!--  <mat-form-field>
         <input matInput placeholder="Domain" type="text" formControlName="domain">
         </mat-form-field>-->
      <mat-form-field>
         <mat-label>Domain</mat-label>
         <mat-select formControlName="domain" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let domain of domainList" [value]="domain.value">
            {{domain.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
         <mat-label>Environment</mat-label>
         <mat-select formControlName="environment" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let environment of environmentList" [value]="environment.value">
            {{environment.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <br />
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `patchValue` or `setValue` (ts file) on specific event where you want to bind data with your form

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because you're passing in an object to `this.form.setValue()` that doesn't have the properties you defined in your form group.
Your `server` object needs to have all these properties. Consider using a model.